# How do I make wget save 4xx response?

Tags: http, response, wget, http-status-codes

When I use wget and the server returns a 4xx response, wget does not store the response body. It just creates an empty file. I cannot find an option for this in the help. Is there a way to make wget store the response body no matter what the status code is? Thanks!